# What is the relation between $\operatorname{int}f(S) $ and $ f(\operatorname{int}S)$ & $f(\overline S)$ and $ \overline {f(S)} $

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

$\newcommand{\int}{\operatorname{int}}$Let $ f: \mathbb R→ \mathbb R $ be a continuous function and let $S$ be a non-empty proper subset of $\mathbb R$ . Which one of the following statements is always true? (Here $\overline A$ denotes the closure of A and $\operatorname{int}A $ denotes the interior of A.)

A. $\operatorname{int}f(S) \subseteq f(\operatorname{int}S)$

B. $f(\overline S) \subseteq \overline {f(S)} $

C. $f(\overline S) \supseteq \overline {f(S)} $

D. $\operatorname{int}f(S) \supseteq f(\operatorname{int}S)$

I am totally confused with this question and need logical proof against the correct answer and also give the reasons why other options are not correct.

Comment: $f(x) = x^2$ and $S = \Bbb R$ will help you with D.

Comment: Why I will take S=$\mathbb R$ ? In the Q. it is given that S is a proper subset of $\mathbb R$

Comment: Alright, take $S = \Bbb R - \{1\}$ The problem occurs at 0.

Comment: But what you are saying is a particular case. Can you give me the proof in more generalized format ??

Comment: If D fails here, then it obviously isn't always true, now is it?

Comment: Okay,fine. So what about the other options?

Comment: For b, consider that for $\Bbb R$, a point is in the closure of a set if and only if there is a sequence of points within the set that converges to it. And note that since $f$ is continuous, $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = f(\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_n)$.

Comment: For$\mathbb R$ -{$1$}.....     
A. $(0,\infty)$$\subseteq$$[0,\infty)$    

B. $[0,\infty)$$\subseteq$$[0,\infty)$     

C. $[0,\infty)$$\supseteq$$[0,\infty)$

Now how can you sure about that these options will always hold ??

Comment: For C, consider $\Bbb R -\{0\}$ and $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$

Comment: You can show that "there exists" statements are true and "for all" statements are false by specific examples. To show "for all" statements (such as these) to be true and "there exists: statements to be false does not follow from specific examples. And I only offered $f(x) = x^2$ as a counterexample to D, not A, B, or C.

Comment: Okay, thank you... C is also omitted.. Now what about A, B ??

Comment: I've already answered B. And for A, consider replacing $S$ with $\Bbb R - S$ and $f(S)$ with $\Bbb R - f(S)$.

Comment: OK,, Sorry Sorry ... Now i find it...  :-) Thank u very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is B. A proof is as follows:

Proof of B: Suppose $f$ is continuous. Then for any $S\subset X$
$$
S \subset f^{-1}(f(S)) \subset f^{-1}(\overline{f(S))}
$$
Since $\overline{f(S)}$ is closed, by continuity of $f$, $f^{-1}(\overline{f(S)})$ is closed. And
$$
S\subset f^{-1}(\overline{f(S)})\implies  \overline{S}\subset \overline{f^{-1}(\overline{f(S)})}=f^{-1}(\overline{f(S)})
$$
Thus
$$
f(\bar S) \subset f(f^{-1}(\overline{f(S)})) \subset \overline{f(S)}
$$
Here we use the fact that
$$
S \subset f^{-1}(f(S))\quad\text{and}\quad f(f^{-1}(S)) \subset S
$$
As well as
$$
A\subset B\implies \overline{A}\subset \overline{B}\quad\text{and}\quad\overline{\overline{A}}=\overline{A}
$$
For A, a counter example is the Cantor function.

For D, a counter example is $f(x)=x^2, \:S=(-1,1]$.

Comment: I have a confusion in the 2nd line,

Let $f$ is $sine $ function, then $f^{-1}(x) = sin^{-1}(x) $ is inverse function of $f(x)$

Let $S=[0,2\pi]$ then $f(S)=[-1,1]$ but $f^{-1}(f(S))=[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$

then $S\not\subset f^{-1}(f(S))$

Comment: You can also see that sine function is continuous. ...

Comment: $f$ is $1-1$ only on $[−π/2,π/2]$. So $f^{-1}$ exists on that. Since $S$ is beyond it, $f^{-1}$ becomes multi-valued function.