# an open continuous image of a Baire space is a Baire space

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, baire-category

Let $(X,\tau)$ and $(Y,\tau_1)$ be topological spaces and $f:(X,\tau) \rightarrow (Y,\tau_1)$ be a continuous open mapping. If $(X,\tau)$ is a Baire space, prove that $(Y,\tau_1)$ is a Baire space.

My Proof is that Let $\{X_n\}^\infty_{n=1}$ be a sequence of open dense sets in $X$. Since $X$ is a Baire space, $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty X_n$ is dense. This implies $\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty X_n\right) \cap U \ne \emptyset$ where $U$ is any open set in $X$. Let $x\in \left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty X_n\right) \cap U$, then It would $x$ should be in all $X_n$ and $U$; thus $f(x) \in \left(\bigcap_n^\infty f(X_n)\right)\cap f(U)$. $f(X_n)$ and $f(U)$ is open in $Y$ since $f$ is continuous open mapping function. This holds for all $x$ and $U$. Hence $Y$ is a Baire space.

In this proof, I assume that $f(X_n)$ is an open dense set in $Y$. Can I do that? if so, why am I allowed to do this?

If anything wrong, please correct me. Thanks

Comment: You didn't prove that for every countable sequence of dense sets $Y_n \subset Y$, $\bigcap_n Y_n $ is dense in $Y$. You **must** start the proof with a sequence of dense open set in $Y$. And no, $f(X_n)$ is not necesssary dense, as $f(X)$ can be much smaller than $Y$

Comment: It isn’t necessarily true unless $f$ is surjective.

Comment: Assuming $f $is surjective and  continuous ,  and $V=Y\backslash Cl_Y (f(X_n))$  then$ f^{-1}V$ is an  open set in $X$ which is disjoint from $X_n$ so $ f^{-1}V=\phi$  so $V=\phi$ so $ f(X_n)$ is dense in $Y.$ In other words the  image  of a dense set under a continuous surjection is dense in the image space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\{Y_n\}^\infty_{n=1}$ be a sequence of open dense sets in $Y$. If $(Y,\tau_1)$ is not a Baire space, then there is an open set $V\subset Y$ that $\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty Y_n\right) \cap V =\varnothing$. So there is
$$
f^{-1}\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty Y_n\right) \cap f^{-1}(V) =\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty f^{-1}(Y_n) \cap f^{-1}(V) =f^{-1}(\varnothing)=\varnothing\tag1
$$
Since $f$ is continuous open, $f^{-1}$ is continuous. By [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1405913/what-is-the-relation-between-operatornameintfs-and-f-operatornameint/1406301#1406301), there is 
$$
f^{-1}(\overline S) \subset \overline {f^{-1}(S)}
$$
Let $f^{-1}(Y_n)=X_n$. Then $\overline{Y_n}=Y$ for $Y_n$ is dense in $Y$. Assume $f$ be surjective. Then $X=f^{-1}(Y)$. 
Hence
$$
X=f^{-1}(Y)=f^{-1}(\overline{Y_n})\subset \overline {f^{-1}(Y_n)}\subset \overline{X_n}
$$
Thus $\overline{X_n}=X$, i.e. $X_n$ is dense in $X$.

Let $U=f^{-1}(V)$. Since $f$ is continuous, $U$ is open. Also  $X_n$ is open for  $Y_n$ is open. So $(1)$ becomes
$$
\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty X_n \cap U=\varnothing
$$
which contradict $X$ is Baire space.

Comment: You need to specify that $f$ is surjective, as otherwise $f^{-1}[V]$ may be empty. For example, let $Y$ be the topological sum of $X$ and $\Bbb Q$, and for $q\in\Bbb Q$ let $Y_q=Y\setminus\{q\}$; clearly $Y_q$ is a dense open subset of $Y$. Let $f:X\to Y:x\mapsto x$; $f$ is continuous and open, but $Y$ is never Baire, since $\bigcap_{q\in\Bbb Q}Y_q=X$, which is not dense in $Y$.

Comment: Yeah, f is assumed to be subjective for $X=f^{-1}(Y)$.

Comment: The OP probably hasn’t seen your last comment: you need to use @user1292919, with the `@` prefix, to make sure that he is notified that he has a comment addressed to him.

Comment: @hermes yes i understood the proof. But one thing, how can you assumen$f$ is surjective?